# jquery: error message location for input validation

Tags: jquery, position, validation

I want to validate input for a radio group named Verify.
If there is no radio button selected during form submission,
I want its error message display under the table.
The following code is not working. I have no idea where goes wrong.
Can somebody help please?

```
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            verify: "required",
        } });
```

---

```
<style type="text/css">
.block { display: block; }
form.form label.error { display: none; }    
</style>
```

---

```
<form id="form" name="form" class="form">
<table><tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="verify" id="verify" value="Verified" />
     Verified</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="verify" id="not_verify" value="Not verified" />Not verified</td></tr></table>
<label for="verify" class="error">Please select verification status.</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use validate property in your radio buttons like `validate="required:true"` for this,

```
<form id="form" name="form" class="form">
<table><tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="verify" id="verify" value="Verified" validate="required:true"/>
     Verified</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="verify" id="not_verify" value="Not verified" validate="required:true"/>Not verified</td></tr></table>
<input type="submit" name="form" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
<label for="verify" class="error">Please select verification status.</label>
</form>
```